# Предложение между двумя символами

Tags: php

Подскажите как можно вытащить предложение между двумя символами?
К примеру `? Мы открылись окончательно и бесповоротно! ?`

В данном случае между вопросительными знаками ?

Comment: В простейшем случае - найти позицию первого `?` в строке, затем - позицию второго `?`. А затем взять подстроку, определенную этими позициями.

Comment: ```$res_arr = explode('?', $target_string);``` У вас получится массив с тремя элементами, где первый эл - все что до первого знака ?, второй все что между, третий - все что после. Логично, что все что вам нужно - это использовать ```$res_arr[1];```

Comment: Спасибо! Сразу в голову не пришло

Comment: тогда проще `[,$result] = explode(...)`